# Pandas / Databricks - Creating a new datetime column if another datetime columns has x in minutes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, databricks

I am new to python so if there is a solution to this somewhere else I apologize.

I have a dataframe that has a column that consist of a timestamps (y-m-d-h-m-s). What I require change the timestamps of that current column minutes has:

- if 10 min then add 5 min
- if 20 min add 10 min
- if 30 min add 15 min
- if 40 min add 20 min
- if 50 min is null
- if 60/00 min is nulll

I Believe it would be something like:

```
 df.loc[df['column'].dt.minute == 10, 'column'] = 15
```

Summary, I am trying to change a column that has 10 minute intervals into 15 minute intervals.

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

For multiple conditions like this `np.select()` is a convenient function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# if 10 min then add 5 min
# if 20 min add 10 min
# if 30 min add 15 min
# if 40 min add 20 min
# if 50 min is null
# if 60/00 min is nulll

df = pd.DataFrame({"date":pd.date_range("1-may-2021","1-may-2021 1:09", freq="5min")})
df["cond"] = np.select([df.date.dt.minute==c for c in [10,20,30,40,50,60,0]],[5,10,15,20,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 0)
```

|  | date | cond |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | nan |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 00:05:00 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-05-01 00:10:00 | 5 |
| 3 | 2021-05-01 00:15:00 | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-05-01 00:20:00 | 10 |
| 5 | 2021-05-01 00:25:00 | 0 |
| 6 | 2021-05-01 00:30:00 | 15 |
| 7 | 2021-05-01 00:35:00 | 0 |
| 8 | 2021-05-01 00:40:00 | 20 |
| 9 | 2021-05-01 00:45:00 | 0 |
| 10 | 2021-05-01 00:50:00 | nan |
| 11 | 2021-05-01 00:55:00 | 0 |
| 12 | 2021-05-01 01:00:00 | nan |
| 13 | 2021-05-01 01:05:00 | 0 |